# verificar se o email ja existe

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Criei essa função para verificar se um email já existe no DB

```
let errors = [];

function ValidationContract() {
    errors = [];
}

// verifica a validade do email e se o mesmo ja existe no banco
ValidationContract.prototype.isValidEmail = (value) => {
    const reg = new RegExp(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/);
    if (!reg.test(value)) { errors.push({message: messageEmailInvalid}) }

    mongodb.connect((err, db) => {
        db.collection('users').findOne({email: value}, (err, res) => {
            if (res && res.email === value) { errors.push({ message: messageEmailExist }) }
        })
    });    
}

ValidationContract.prototype.errors = () => { 
    return errors; 
}

ValidationContract.prototype.isValid = () => {
    return errors.length == 0;
}
```

mas quando aplico ela na rota simplesmente não funciona

```
app.post('/users/', async(req, res, next) => {

        let contract = new validationContract()
        await contract.isValidEmail(req.body.email)
        if (!contract.isValid()) {
            res.status(400).send(contract.errors()).end()
            return
        }
}
```

Alguém sabe me explicar aonde eu estou errando ou o que estou esquecendo

Comment: nao irá funcionar porque nao sabes quando recebes o erro da base de dados, tens de esperar e só proceder quando souberes a resposta (async), para tal efeito tens de usar promessas (ou callback). o método `isValid()` nao está à espera da resposta da base de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nao complicando o codigo, o que apenas se está esquecendo, é que a coneccao à base de dados dá-se de uma forma asyncrona, ou seja, não sabe se demora 1ms ou 3s a receber a resposta, mas, pelo codigo que apresenta, espera que a resposta seja syncrona.

eu apenas usava uma funcao:

```
const isValidEmail = (email, cb) => {
    const reg = new RegExp(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/);
    if (!reg.test(email)) {
        // nao é um email valido, nao vale a pena perguntar se existe na DB
        cb(new Error('RegEx: Email nao é valido'));
        return;
    }

    mongodb.connect((err, db) => {
        db.collection('users').findOne({email: value}, (err, res) => {
            if (res && res.email === value) { 
                // email existe na base de dados
                cb(new Error('DB: Email existente'));
            } else {
                cb(null); // OK
            }
        })
    });    
}
```

e na sua funcao, apenas:

```
app.post('/users/', (req, res) => {

    const email = req.body.email;
    isValidEmail(email, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(400).send(err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Valeu cara faz pouco tempo que comecei a estudar node.js e ainda to aprendendo sobre "asyncronidade"

Answer (score 0):

A resposta acima, fica um pouco mais "clean", mas caso queira continuar com a sua lógica o problema está no seguinte código:

```js
app.post('/users/', async(req, res, next) => {
      let contract = new validationContract()
      await contract.exists(req.body.email) //<- exists troque por isValidEmail
      if (!contract.isValid()) {
        res.status(400).send(contract.errors()).end()
        return
      }
    }
```

Você vinculou a function ao protótipo porém chamou uma coisa que não foi definida

Comment: O erro ali foi meu, na verdade quando eu postei a pergunta aqui já tinha corrigido o nome da function no meu código